# Adding a private CA to Openjdk11 cacerts

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, idempiere

I need to be able to use our private PKI CA to authenticate with a Java application.  Specifically, I need to be able to securely send email through our smart hub originating on a host running iDempiere.

I am testing this using the SSLPoke class.

```
JAVA_VERSION="11" java SSLPoke mx32.harte-lyne.ca 465
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

My research indicates that this error is commonly encountered when the CA certificate for the destination host certificate is not found in the `lib/security/cacerts` file.

I have added our private CA certs [hll] to `cacerts` and verified that they are present:

```
JAVA_VERSION="11" keytool -list  -rfc  -cacerts > cacerts.txt
grep 'Alias' cacerts.txt
. . .
lias name: godaddyclass2ca [jdk]
Alias name: godaddyrootg2ca [jdk]

Alias name: hartelyneissuer2016 [hll]
Alias name: hartelyneroot2016 [hll]

Alias name: identrustcommercial [jdk]
Alias name: identrustdstx3 [jdk]
. . .
```

And yet, when I test this using the `SSLPoke` class I get this error:

```
JAVA_VERSION="11" java SSLPoke mx32.harte-lyne.ca 465
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:369)
```

What else is required to get our CA certs to be recognised by Java?

Comment: (this isn't really a programming question/problem but) that should do it; try looking at the cert(s) received from the server with `keytool -printcert -sslserver hostname:port` to make sure what you are getting matches what you expect(ed) and installed.

Comment: You are right.  I tried your suggestion and I am not getting the expected result.  There has to be some configuration issue on our MX service which I am tripping over.